# Username is partially obscured in the chat message

Tags: bug, chat, design, display-names, firefox

User name is partially obscured in [the chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41066666#41066666).

Original screenshot image (100% scale on webpage):

> [image: 100%]

Zoomed (with my red line) image to better show the problem:

> [image: w-obscured]

Looks like only Firefox is affected. Chrome and IE draw name fully.

Yes, I know that this is toooo minor but it's still a design bug (probably on the FF side)!

Comment: Why this horrible quality? It's utterly pixelated. It might be relevant, e.g. maybe you have some zoom in place, and SE does not support zoom.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I'd assume the OP scaled up the screenshot to make the issue easier to see (since the name is only cut off by a pixel or two). Also, I bet this is yet another font metrics issue.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I made a zoom after taking screenshot to better show the problem. I can post the original image itself, if you want it.

Comment: Yes better have both

Comment: oddly, looks fine for me in FF, least with the transcript